# orderBy in ngRepeat using another variable property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

Is it possible to sort items from one array based on another variable by only using orderBy and not adding a count property to the items in the array?

Lets say i have an array and a map in the controller:

```
$scope.x = [{no:1,name:"a"},
    {no:2,name:"b"},
    {no:3,name:"c"}];

$scope.y = { 1: [1],
    2: [1,2,3],
    3: [1,2] };
```

and the html will look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in x | orderBy: y[i.no].length">
  {{i.no}}
  {{ y[i.no] }}
  {{ y[i.no].length }}
</div>
```

output:

```
1 [1] 1
2 [1,2,3] 3
3 [1,2] 2
```

but it should be:

```
1 [1] 1
3 [1,2] 2
2 [1,2,3] 3
```

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: yes thank you dev8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a predicate function, to specify your condition.

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in x | orderBy: findOrder">
    {{i.no}}
    {{ y[i.no] }}
    {{ y[i.no].length }}
</div>
```

And:

```
$scope.findOrder = function(elem){
      console.log(elem.no);
      return $scope.y[elem.no].length;
 }
```

A [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auc49a4L/).